# Java 8 map merge method

Tags: java, dictionary, merge, java-8

I am trying to create a HashMap that will contain an integer as a key and a list of strings as a value:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>(30);
```

I want to somehow populate it efficiently. What I came up was:

```
map.merge(search_key, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new_string)), (v1, v2) -> {
                    v1.addAll(v2);
                    return v1;
                });
```

This code is small and *elegant* but my problem is that I create a new **List** in every call. Is there any way that I can skip the List creation after the first merge, and just add new_string in the first created list?

Comment: “This code is small and elegant” but broken. Trying to invoke `addAll` on the result of `Arrays.asList` won’t work…

Comment: @Holger You are right. My mistake is that Arrays.asList(new_string) gives a fixed list, I will fix it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use the method [Map::computeIfAbsent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to create a list lazily:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(search_key, k -> new ArrayList<>())
   .add(new_string);
```